# Why doesn't there exists a subi opcode for MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture, instructions, instruction-set

I am very new to **Assembly language**. I was reading about **MIPS** architecture and came to know that you have `addi` opcode but there is no `subi` opcode. Why don't we have a `subi` opcode?

Comment: Near-duplicate [What is the "relationship" between addi and subi?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11981660).  Some MIPS assemblers implement `subi` as a pseudo-instructions.  (including the MARS simulator but not SPIM.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you create an instruction set, you're bound by some constraints, such as the total number of instructions you can create. The MIPS creators realized that there isn't a need for `subi` (because you can add a negative number with `addi` using 2's complement), and they simply made the decision to forego making that instruction. It may have been to conserve the number of instructions, or just simply because it isn't needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So they followed there rule, i.e "Less is more."

Comment: @JustAnotherProgrammer - that's probably the case.  Good luck with MIPS!  [Patterson and Hennessy](http://www.amazon.com/Computer-Organization-Design-Fourth-Architecture/dp/0123744938/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1312318028&sr=8-1) is a great book for learning computer architecture (the bible), and the [SPIM simulator](http://spimsimulator.sourceforge.net/) is a decent tool if you want to practice your MIPS assembly.

Comment: Why is 'sub' needed then? Can't we use 'add' to do any 'sub' operation by taking 2's complement

Comment: @mskd96 Yes, you could perform a `sub` that way, so it is not strictly necessary. But, unless there is another important operation that would be omitted from the ISA by including `sub`, it isn't detrimental to include it in the ISA.

Comment: @mskd96 you forgot 1 of  Patterson and Hennessy's design principles: *"Make the common case fast"*. `sub` is much more common than `subi` with immediates larger than 32767 so that'll why the instruction was introduced, otherwise we can have a complete instruction set with [only 1 instruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_instruction_set_computer) and also very slow to do common things. "Good design demands good compromises"

Answer (score 4):

Both `addi` and `addiu` take 16-bit signed immediates as operand, so it makes no sense to add separate `subi` and `subiu` opcodes.

Comment: They could easily have added a subi opcode to the assembler that maps to the same hardware instruction.

Comment: @Bo Any decent MIPS assembler does support subi mnemonic (which emits addi).

Comment: @Bo Persson: then it wouldn't be an opcode, but a pseudo-instruction :)

Comment: Just a question: is immediate in `addi` sign-extended when being added to a register?

Comment: @user35443: yes, also for `ADDIU` (`ADDIU` only differs from `ADDI` in that it does not raise Overflow Exceptions)