# Why would we use addiu instead of addi?

Tags: assembly, mips, addition, unsigned, immediate-operand

In MIPS assembly, what is the benefit of using `addiu` over `addi`? Isn't `addiu` unsigned (and will ruin our calculations?)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> and will ruin our calculations

No, MIPS uses [*two's complement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), hence the same instruction for addition/subtraction can be used for both signed and unsigned operations. There's no difference in the result.

That's also true for bitwise instructions, non-widening multiplication and many other operations. See

- [Which arithmetic operations are the same on unsigned and two's complement signed numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21475286/995714)
- [Difference between signed and unsigned on bitwise operations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13229313/995714)

The only difference between them is that `addi` generates a trap when overflow while `addiu` doesn't. So `addi` and its overflow family (`add`, `sub`...) is often useless. In fact it's so rarely used that [`addi` was removed in MIPSr6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#MIPS32/MIPS64_Release_6) to release valuable opcode space to other instructions

Here the instruction name is extremely misleading, because it's not actually an "unsigned" addition. The immediate is still *sign extended* instead of zero extended. So `addiu $1, $2, 0xFFFF` will actually subtract 1 from `$2` instead of adding 65535 to it.

> Despite its name, add immediate unsigned (`addiu`) is used to add constants to signed integers when we don't care about overflow. MIPS has no subtract immediate instruction, and negative numbers need sign extension, so the MIPS architects decided to sign-extend the immediate field.
>
> [Computer Organization and Design: The Hardware/software Interface
> By David A. Patterson, John L. Hennessy](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=DMxe9AI4-9gC&pg=PA276&lpg=PA276&dq=mips+addiu+sign+extend&source=bl&ots=w-Ik_5eGgJ&sig=LPBP5GBNUAa4R8pgdeIRflyF2-s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-oaHlgK3ZAhWFr48KHdGWC5YQ6AEIfDAI#v=onepage&q=mips%20addiu%20sign%20extend&f=false)

Read more [Difference between add and addu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16634110/995714)

Comment: I thought MIPS numbers are 32bit, so `addiu $1, $2, 0xFFFFFFFF` should substract 1 from `$2`, and using `0xFFFF` should only add that amount (as long as it fits obviously). Or am I wrong?

Comment: @snowflake MIPS instructions are 32-bit long, hence you can't encode a 32-bit constant in them. I-type instructions contain only a 16-bit immediate which will be sign-extended to 32 bits in most cases, including `addiu` case

Comment: The names seems to match C undefined-behaviour semantics, where signed overflow is undefined (and MIPS `addi` traps), but unsigned overflow is defined as wrapping (which `addiu` implements).  Of course, many compilers choose to actually implement wrapping semantics for signed integers, too, and use `addu` / `addiu` for everything.  It's still a weird naming convention, but this is how to remember how they work, and why it makes sense that it has nothing to do with how the 16-bit immediate is treated.