# subi instruction in MIPs

Tags: mips

I am writing a program in MIPs bare mode and when I try to run it in QtSpim it tells me I have a syntax error in line 40 which is the subi instruction. Can you help explain why that is happening and also if there are any other problems in my code. Also would this work in bare mode?

```
.data 0x10002000
map:
    .ascii " ##  ###"
    .ascii "       *"
    .ascii "       #"
    .ascii "  ###   "
    .ascii "        "
    .ascii "   #### "
    .ascii "        "
    .ascii "S ## ## "
    
map2:    .space 64  # Dynamic map at 0x10003000
player:  .space 1  # Space to store player location 1 byte

prompt1: .asciiz "Use WASD keys to move.\n"
prompt2: .asciiz "Enter your move (WASD): "

.text
    la $t0, map     # Load the address of the game map
    la $t1, map2    # Load the address of the dynamic map

    li $t2, 64  # Number of bytes to copy
    
copyMap:  # Loop to copy each byte from the game map to the dynamic map
    lb $t3, 0($t0)    # Load a byte from the game map
    sb $t3, 0($t1)    # Store the byte in the dynamic map
    addi $t0, $t0, 1  # Move to the next byte in the game map
    addi $t1, $t1, 1  # Move to the next byte in the dynamic map
    subi $t2, $t2, $1  # Subtract 1 from the byte count
    bnez $t2, copyMap  # Continue the loop if there are more bytes to copy

    la $a0, map2  # Call printMap function with the address of the dynamic map
    jal printMap

printMap:
    li $t0, 0       # counter for the row
    la $t1, ($a0)   # Load the address of the map

printLoop:
    lb $t2, 0($t1)  # Load a byte from the map

    beqz $t2, printDone # Check if the end of the map is reached

    li $v0, 11       # syscall to print character
    move $a0, $t2    # print character
    syscall

    addi $t0, $t0, 1  # Add 1 to counter for the row


    li $t3, 8    # Check if we reached the end of the row every 8 characters
    beq $t0, $t3, printNewLine

    addi $t1, $t1, 1   # Move to the next byte in the map
    j printLoop

printNewLine:
    li $v0, 11
    li $a0, '\n'
    syscall

    li $t0, 0  # Start row counter at 0 for next loop
    j print_loop

printDone:
    jr $ra   # Exit the function
```

for the Mips program to run.

Comment: Did you mean `subi $t2, $t2, 1`?

Comment: I had it like that originally and it still gave me a syntax error.

Comment: Are you sure `subi` is even supported? Can you use `addi` with `-1` instead?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981660/what-is-the-relationship-between-addi-and-subi

Comment: MIPS has no `subi` instruction in machine code, but many assemblers will take that as a pseudo instruction substituting with `addi` and negated constant.  You can do that yourself if the assembler doesn't take the `subi`.